# Terraform unable to find azurerm backend storage during init

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I've created an Azure Storage Account to be used as the backend state store for Terraform, and I was able to write to this from an Azure DevOps pipeline running Terraform commands.  I can see the container in the Storage Account and confirm that it has the state content from the pipeline execution in it with that same key.  However, when I try to run Terraform "manually" using the same backend store, I'm getting an error that it cannot find that container:

```
$ terraform init -backend-config="storage_account_name=<redacted>" -backend-config="container_name=auto-api-tfstate" -backend-config="access_key=<redacted>" -backend-config="key=dev-internal2/dev-internal2.tfstate:us"
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...
Backend configuration changed!

Terraform has detected that the configuration specified for the backend
has changed. Terraform will now check for existing state in the backends.



Error: Error inspecting states in the "azurerm" backend:
    storage: service returned error: StatusCode=404, ErrorCode=ContainerNotFound, ErrorMessage=The specified container does not exist.
RequestId:89a9b361-a01e-00b1-0fb4-ba5d51000000
Time:2021-10-06T13:18:41.2460433Z, RequestInitiated=Wed, 06 Oct 2021 13:18:40 GMT, RequestId=89a9b361-a01e-00b1-0fb4-ba5d51000000, API Version=2016-05-31, QueryParameterName=, QueryParameterValue=

Prior to changing backends, Terraform inspects the source and destination
states to determine what kind of migration steps need to be taken, if any.
Terraform failed to load the states. The data in both the source and the
destination remain unmodified. Please resolve the above error and try again.
```

My main.tf file has simply:

```
terraform {
    backend "azurerm" {}
}
```

As mentioned, this same `terraform init` command worked when invoked in a Bash script in an ADO pipeline, so not sure what may be the issue.  Any suggestions for debugging this appreciated.

Comment: What about the identity you're using to authenticate to azure from the pipeline vs manually? Does that identity has the right permissions like Storage Blob Data Reader? Did you create the storage account and container manually or it's taken care of by the pipeline? Which version of terraform are you using?

Comment: @KedMardemootoo:

- I created the Azure Storage account & container manually, so it's not a timing issue (particularly given the use of Terraform in the pipeline was able to write its state to the container).
- The identity is the access key from the Azure portal blade for the storage account.  And the "terraform init" syntax I'm using manually is the same as the pipeline runs.

Comment: @KedMardemootoo, also the version of Terraform is v0.12.6 (admittedly old but it's compatible with the open source provider we're using).

Answer (score 0):

Uncovered the issue ... there was state information in the .terraform folder which conflicted with the new backend.  Once I cleared that out, the "terraform init" command worked as expected.